# How to port BlackBerry Application from OS 5 to OS 6

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-os6, blackberry-os5, blackberry-os-v5

I have developed application for BlackBerry OS 5 and now I want to port it to BB OS 6

While porting app, I am facing following issue --

I have added separate org.json.me package in OS 5 which is inbuilt in OS 6

When I add BB OS 6 library instead of OS 5 in the app it gives me error

Please suggest possible solution to run same app on both platforms

Comment: your OS 5.0 build will work in OS 6.0's devices.But when u tried to work with os 6 than u have to remove external json file and used inbuilt json. so just install .cod file in OS 6.0's simulator and test.

Comment: Thanx Coder for prompt reply
Do I have to post two different .cod files on BlackBerry AppWorld? I also want to distribute this app on BB OS 7 platform. Then i have to post 3 different .cod files on AppWorld

Comment: yes @Silwar we can distrubute different .cod file for different OS version in app world. When we are upload app to app world there is option to publish different cod files for different different OS version .

Comment: Thanx Coder this will definitely help me lot in my future apps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have got answer to my question

I used BlackBerry OS 5 library to compile my application which is running excellent in OS 6 device also

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the package name of your json package to com.yourcompany.json instead of leaving it as org.json.me. This is a simple solution to your problem, there might be better solutions as well.

Comment: Hi rfsk2010, yes this will work but I dont think so that this is standard way to do this